# How do I check a users input value from the console against an array element? c#

Tags: c#, arrays, validation

I have read in unit conversions using a text file and stored them in an `array`.

I plan to get the user input of each measurement they would like to convert and compare them to the `element` in the `array` so I can quote them to enter a valid input.

The data in my array is split with the use of `(",")`

The data in the array is organised in this format. e.g. "ounce,gram,28.0"

How do I check that the user has entered a vald input? For example they put ounce where ounce was not another incompatible measurement like pint.

Here is what I have kind of done so far

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program myProgram = new Program();//call for program to start 
        myProgram.RunProgram();

    }
    public string inputA;
    PUBLIC STRING InputB;
    public decimal inputC;
    string[] finalArray;

    public class Conversion
    {
        public string measurementA { set; get; }
        public string measurementB { set; get; }
        public decimal converFac { set; get; }

    }
    public void RunProgram()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to to our Conversion Calculator");
        ReadFile();//read in text file
        GetInput();//get the user input
        //Validation();//validate it according to the data in the text file, redirect to getInput is not validated correctly
        //Display();//display the result accordingly if validated correctly
        //ReDo();//offer a restart or an exit to the program
    }

    public void ReadFile()
    {

        List<Conversion> Convert = new List<Conversion>();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"U:\convert.txt"))
        {
            while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                string str;
                string[] srArray;
                str = sr.ReadLine();

                srArray = str.Split(',');
                Conversion currentConversion = new Conversion();
                currentConversion.measurementA = srArray[0];
                currentConversion.measurementB = srArray[1];
                currentConversion.converFac = decimal.Parse(srArray[2]);
                finalArray = (string[])srArray.Clone();

            }


        }
    }
    public void GetInput()
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter your first unit of Measurement.");
        inputA = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        //what do I put her to make sure that it corresponds with one of the measurementA elements in the array?

    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!
EDIT: Bump

Comment: I have tried to make the question slightly more clear. Comment if there is any other problems you see.

Answer (score 0):

use `try` `catch`

You Can modify this to give better output error like **:File is incorrect at line number:**

```
public List<Conversion> ReadFile()
    {

        List<Conversion> Convert = new List<Conversion>();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"U:\convert.txt"))
        {
            while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                string str;
                string[] srArray;
                str = sr.ReadLine();

                srArray = str.Split(',');
                Conversion currentConversion = new Conversion();
                currentConversion.measurementA = srArray[0];
                currentConversion.measurementB = srArray[1];
                try{
                currentConversion.converFac = decimal.Parse(srArray[2]);
                    }
                catch(Exception ex){
                Console.WriteLine("File is not in correct format");
                break;
                }
                Convert.Add(currentConversion);

            }


        }
   return Convert;
    }
```

Comment: I am trying to validate the users input into the console not the file. Sorry I should of made it more clear.

Comment: User input also can be validated similarly

Comment: could you demonstrate this in the GetInput method for clarity purposes please :)

Comment: There is no method of obtaining a user input in this code. The file being read in is stored in an array. I then want to prompt the user to enter a phrase such as "pounds" into the console for his first measurement under `GetInput` after this has been entered I need to get a second measurement form the user. Once these inputs have been entered I then need to check them against the array so that they are compatible measurement formats. E.G Pounds, Ounces, Valid. Pint, Miles, Not valid.

Answer (score 0):

To compare the units of measurement in a array, use the Array.Find method as shown below

```
static void Main()
{
   string[] array1 = { "kgs", "pounds"};
   string value1 = Array.Find(array1,element => element=="kgs");
   Console.WriteLine(value1);
   Console.ReadKey();
}
```